# Cant show log in the function in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to use console.log inside the function but it doesnt works, its even doesnt show any errors. When i trie to use " console.log("I") ", it doesnt show in inspect.

```
$scope.compareVal = function(typetext){
   console.log("I");
   var transformedInput = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      console.log("I");
      if($scope.txtArea[i].toLowerCase() === $scope.typetext[i].toLowerCase()){
         transformedInput += $scope.typetext[i];
      }else{
         transformedInput += $scope.typetext[i];
      }
   }
   return transformedInput;
};
```

Comment: from where you call compareVal () ?

Comment: are you sure you are calling that function?

Comment: Where are you calling this function from ? Maybe some html file with angularjs, post that also.

Comment: ensure that you checked  js in webconsole

Comment: can't I show log without calling that function ?

Comment: If you don't call the function, none of the code inside the function gets executed. So no, you can't.

Comment: how can i call this type of function ?

Comment: onload='compareVal(typetext)' i tried to call function like this but it doesnt work

Comment: @drosan you need an event. Where is that function written ? In a controller ? just add $scope.compareVal() after defining it. Do you want to call in a click button ? use ng-click="compareVal()" instead. Show us a fiddle to see where is your function defined